# Changing just database giving sess_write_close() error

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Everything was working fine with database running locally. When I connected to remote database having same exact schema I am getting this error

```
Severity: Warning

Message: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: C:\xampp\tmp)

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

Filename is not shown and nothing backtrace so I can't find much on it.

Comment: I would check your code for a 
[session_save_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) definition. Obviously, either the tmp directory does not exist on the remote machine, or the proper permissions to write to it are off.

Comment: The `/tmp` directory can vary from server to server. If you're on a shared server, you may need to change the tmp directory on your remote machine e.g.  `session_save_path('/home/example.com/sessions');`